# Is there a pandas function to evaluate if a substring is in a given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm filtering a Pandas Serie in order to find if the rows are substrings of a given string.
I tried those instructions but couldn't succeed:

```
sting_to_test = "My String"
filtered_data = my_serie[my_serie in sting_to_test]
```

I also tested the `isin()` function but it seems that this can't be used in a single sting.

```
sting_to_test = "My String"
filtered_data = my_serie.isin(sting_to_test)
```

Is there any solution without iterating on the whole serie with a loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `apply` and `lambda` as following:

```
my_series = pd.Series(['AB', 'CD', 'BA'])
test_str = 'ABC'
print(my_series.apply(lambda row: row in test_str))
```

Comment: Actually I need the inverse operation, I want to check if the rows are substrings of the test_str

Comment: Updated the condition.